# How can I make a rectangle selection tool in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to make a simple game in which the user can select units on the screen using an RTS-style box selection (ex. StarCraft, Warcraft). After digging through a lot of stuff I found on Google and from other people, I'm still not getting how it's done.

When looking around I found this:

```
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import *


# set up pygame
pygame.init()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()


# set up the window
WINDOWWIDTH = 700
WINDOWHEIGHT = 700
CAPTION = 'RTS SELCTION BOX TEST'
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption(CAPTION)


# set constants
# set up the colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
# color of background
BACKGROUNDCOLOR = GREEN
# set these values to avoid errors on startup
draw_new_selection_box = False
selection_completed = False
# test units (boxes)
units = [1,2]
units[0] = pygame.Rect((100, 200), (40, 40))
units[1] = pygame.Rect((300, 360), (40, 40))
selected_units = []


# game loop
game_loop = True
while game_loop:
    # check for events and change variables based on events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # check if user has quit
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
  
        check_which_mouse_button = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if check_which_mouse_button[0]:
                leftclick_down_location = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                draw_new_selection_box = True
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            if not check_which_mouse_button[0]:
                leftclick_up_location = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                draw_new_selection_box = False
                selection_completed = True

    
    # use event variables to change variables
    current_mouse_location = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if draw_new_selection_box:
        selection_box_x = current_mouse_location[0] - leftclick_down_location[0]
        selection_box_y = current_mouse_location[1] - leftclick_down_location[1]
        selection_box = pygame.Rect((leftclick_down_location), (selection_box_x, selection_box_y))
    elif selection_completed:
        completed_selection_box_x = leftclick_up_location[0] - leftclick_down_location[0]
        completed_selection_box_y = leftclick_up_location[1] - leftclick_down_location[1]
        completed_selection_box = pygame.Rect((leftclick_down_location), (completed_selection_box_x, completed_selection_box_y))

                    
    # draw the background onto surface
    windowSurface.fill(BACKGROUNDCOLOR)


    # draw selection box and units onto the Windowsurface
    for unit in units:
        pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, WHITE, unit, 2)
    if draw_new_selection_box:
        pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, RED, selection_box, 2)
        for unit in units:
            if selection_box.colliderect(unit):
                pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, BLUE, unit, 2)
     

    # draw the windowSurface onto the screen
    pygame.display.update()
    mainClock.tick(60)
```

The problem is, when the user tries to make the box go any way except down and left, it either shows no box or a really big one.

This is my first question here, so if I need to clarify I will do the best I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) is created from the top left position and the width and height. The width and height must be positive. You need to find the minimum and maximum x and y coordinates of the 2 points. Write a function that creates the `pygame.Rect` object from the two points:

```py
def create_box(p1, p2):
    x1, y1 = min(p1[0], p2[0]), min(p1[1], p2[1])
    x2, y2 = max(p1[0], p2[0]), max(p1[1], p2[1])
    return pygame.Rect(x1, y1, x2-x1, y2-y1)
```

Or compute absolute value (`abs`) of the distances between the points:

```py
def create_box(p1, p2):
    return pygame.Rect(min(p1[0], p2[0]), min(p1[1], p2[1]),
                       abs(p2[0]-p1[0]), abs(p2[1]-p1[1]))
```

Use the function in the application loop:

```py
game_loop = True
while game_loop:
    # [...]

    current_mouse_location = pygame.mouse.get_pos()   
    if draw_new_selection_box:
        selection_box = create_box(leftclick_down_location, current_mouse_location)
    elif selection_completed:
        completed_selection_box = create_box(leftclick_down_location,
                                             leftclick_up_location)

    # [...]
```

---

Furthermore, [`pygame.draw.rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect)  cannot draw the rectangle correctly if either with or the height is less than twice the width of the outline. For this you have to implement a special case:

```py
game_loop = True
while game_loop:
    # [...]

    if draw_new_selection_box:
        if selection_box.width < 4 or selection_box.height < 4:
            rect = pygame.Rect(*selection_box.topleft, 
                               max(2, selection_box.width), 
                               max(2, selection_box.height))
            pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, RED, rect)
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, RED, selection_box, 2)
```